# Что замещает явно объявленный конструктор копирования?

Tags: c++, ооп

В классе присутствует конструктор по умолчанию, конструктор копирования, конструктор перемещения, оператор присваивания копирования, оператор присваивания перемещения и деструктор. Если мы явно укажем конструктор с параметрами, он заместит конструктор по умолчанию. А если мы явно объявим конструктор копирования, он заместит конструктор по умолчанию или конструктор копирования?

Comment: А как вы себе представляете замену конструктором копирования (с параметром) конструктора по умолчанию (без параметров)?

Comment: Что значит "заместит"? Приведет к удалению? Удалит?

Comment: Под "заместит" стоит понимать "не будет генерировать".

Comment: @free_ze: В С++ понятие "не будет генерировать" на самом деле распадается на два: "не будет объявлять" и "не будет определять" и логика там непростая.

Comment: @AnT А в каком случае не будет определять, но объявит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мы явно определим какой-либо конструктор c параметрами, то компилятор не станет генерировать конструктор по умолчанию. Его можно заставить это сделать явно:

```
class MyType { 
public: 
    MyType()=default; // сгенери, пожалуйста, умолчательный конструктор

    MyType(int i):_i(i){}
   //....
};
```

Конструктор копирования не будет генерироваться, если мы предоставим свою версию.

Чтобы заместить конструктор копирования, нам нужно определить конструктор, параметром которого будет **ссылка** на объект того же типа.

Comment: default вроде бы не обязательное слово. разве не достаточно просто реализовать конструктор без параметров наполнив его своим функционалом.

Comment: @perfect верно, но тогда это будет не сгенерированный компилятором, а пользовательский умолчательный конструктор.

Comment: а зачем тогда нужен метод который ничего не делает? я так понимаю что компилятор со мной солидарен в этом вопросе. Зачем нужна такая конструкция, раскройте секрет.

Comment: @perfect Почему ничего не делает? Он инициализирует поля дефолтными значениями. Пользовательский конструктор с пустым телом и списком инициализации действительно выглядел бы коряво. А если бы мы не объявили дефолтный конструктор ни в каком виде и при этом был бы какой-либо специальный, то мы бы и вовсе потеряли возможность конструировать объекты с помощью вызова дефолтного конструктора.

Comment: я так понимаю что бы переменные члены касса инициализировать дефолтными значениями нужно это вручную делать в конструкторе без параметров. сам по себе он этого не сделает.

Comment: @perfect Чтобы инициализировать члены класса дефолтными значениями необходимо, чтобы у них вызвались конструкторы по умолчанию (или произошла инициализация для простых типов). Их вызов из конструктора генерирует компилятор, если программист не указал иного в списке инициализации. У класса всегда есть как минимум один конструктор, явный или неявный. Поэтому острой необходимости делать это вручную нет.

Comment: class my{int a; my(){}; }; - есть дефолтный конструктор но в (a) все равно будет мусор.

Comment: @perfect Согласен, тут неправ, в случае с пользовательским конструктором в полях будет некое неопределенное значение. Но этого не произойдет, если будет конструктор, сгенерированный компилятором или вызов с {}.

Comment: вот по этому компилятор и убирает дефолный конструктор, потому что программист явно инициализировал обязательные данные которые будут получены при создании объекта. и толку от MyType()=default; я не вижу, может быть это только для отладки понабиться когда нибудь или же это бзик нового стандарта.

Comment: @perfect Не будьте так категоричны, в некоторых ситуациях программиста вполне может устраивать обнуление всего и вся. Куда удобнее написать =default, вместо того, чтобы писать и поддерживать определение со списком инициализации.